# Where can we put our Plugins and Helpers in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I download GOOGLE API PHP Client. Now where should I put it in my laravel directory ? and how can I access to it in a Controller class?

Comment: You could build a service provider or a facade for it, or just call it wherever. I would probably recommend finding a pre-buildt package for laravel or just install the google api client through composer...

Comment: Best way would probably be to bind it to an interface and inject it through the controller constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want a package you can install it via the package manager, The defacto standard is using composer

execute the following command in terminal from your project directory

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

this will install google api client in your project directory under the `/vendor` folder. then open the `composer.json` and add/append the following code appropriately.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google"
        ],
    }
}
```

then from any of your files, whether its controller or model, you can new up a google client object.

`new \Google_Client();`

Additionally you may want to update your `.env` files with appropriate API keys

Comment: @Mahdi, consider giving an upvote if this answer solved your concern. check this link for finding out how to upvote https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173399/325196

Comment: its fine, when you have enough reputation you can vote, https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up